# Firebase push notification connection issue

Tags: firebase, push-notification, connection

I've tried and tested firebase code with xamarin iOS. Using below code

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging#register-for-remote-notifications

Things well worked with open network but in restricted network firebase site did open but 
Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect (error => { if (error != null) { // Handle if something went wrong while connecting } else { // Let the user know that connection was successful } });

This code failed to connect saying com.google.fcm (501) could not complete operation.
How could I find which address of firebase is blocked because of which it is not able to connect ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi, not a direct answer, i remember was fighting this too, then switched to onesignal.com. Free, works with forms, has api to use in your backend, the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, but with onesignal.com also, I may face this issue.